# Simple GET request with Facebooks API

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am currently taking a course in app development and I am trying to use Facebooks API for GET requests on certain events. My goal is the get a JSON file containing all comments made on a certain event.

However some events return only a an "id" key with an id number such as this:
{
"id": "116445769058883"
}
That happends with this event:
https://www.facebook.com/events/116445769058883/

However other events such as (https://www.facebook.com/events/1964003870536124/) : returns only the latest comment for some reason.

I am experementing with facebook explore API:
https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/

This is the following GET requests that I have been using in the explorer:
GET -> /v.10/facebook-id/?fields=comments

Any ideas? It's really tricky to understand the response since both events have the privacy set to OPEN.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from v2.4 of the API, the API is now [declarative](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/upgrading#v23tov24) which means you'll need to specify what fields you want the API to return.

For example, if you want first name and second name of the user, then you make a GET request to `/me?fields=first_name,last_name` else you will only get back the default fields which are `id` and `name`.

If you want to see what fields are available for a given endpoint, use `metadata` field. e.g. GET `/me?metadata=true`

Comment: Thanks, I used metadata=true.
Comments goes under this: 
 "type": "event",
    "connections": {
comments: s": "https://graph.facebook.com/v2.10/19640038....etc.

This implies that comments are available for the given endpoint. I don't really know how I should proceed. What sort of fields should I use besides comments? Some sort of time limitation?

Comment: I just found out that I can use /feed field in order to read all status updates on the given event. The only slight issue is that I can't see who posted the message.

Comment: It's so weird that I can get the comments by: 
957552644386529/feed and not by:
957552644386529/comments.

Comment: They are 2 different endpoints. `Object-id/feed` will give you all the content posted to the wall for the given object and `Object-id/comments` will give you all the comments for the object. I think you are confusing posts for comments. You might get some clarifications from the docs:
1. Comments: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/object/comments/
2. Feed: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.10/event/feed

Comment: I just learned that yesterday. I solved my issue by doing this request:event-id/feed?fields=from, message, updated_time